search for existing public squares in a city on google maps
Estou criando um projeto via wordpress de comunidade de bairro. Daí preciso de algo que possa corresponder as praças existentes em determinados bairros. No site da prefeitura está uma bagunça, sem condições.
Já criei as API do Google Maps (Java, Mpas) pra isso, mas não consegui localiza-las por lá. Alguém já fez algo parecido que possa contribuir? Gtrato.

Para que a pergunta possa ser tratada dentro do escopo deste site é importante você [edit] e fornecer um [mcve] do problema que não dependa de nenhuma API externa (por exemplo, simulando dados já baixados de forma que não seja necessário ninguém da comunidade consultar links, e que a pergunta continue válida se a API mudar). Caso seja um problema de entendimento/funcionamento da API e não do algoritmo ou do funcionamento da sua parte do código, já seria o caso de buscar suporte diretamente com o fornecedor da API. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor proveito do site.

Vou ver algo e refaço a pergunta no seu devido local. Obrigado.

Isso posto, considere usar o Openstreetmap, que é mantido pelos próprios usuários e você mesmo pode contribuir com a melhoria do mapa..

Perfeito! Estou vendo ele aqui. Obrigado.
